# fail to connect to camera error, but works when I export to apk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-camera

So I am creating and app that uses the camera API. The app is close to done it just needs to have a few more features added. However when I try to launch the app on the emulator or my phone from eclipse it creates a runtime error saying unable to resume activity: fail to connect to camera service. I have tried multiple emulators and yes the camera option is turned on. I am just so confused to why it runs perfect when exported as an apk and installed on my phone but doesnt work when I try to debug it on in or the emulator form eclipse. Any ideas? because it is impossible to error track for me now. Ive looked at tons of posts related to not being able to connect to the camera service but havent had any luck applying it to my circumstance.

**Side note:** Also the camera used to work fine and ran this exact app a few days ago with no troubles. My thinking is that it has something to do with eclipse. Since the app works perfectly on my phone when ran from the apk

**update:** I uninstalled eclipse and re-installed it and same error is still occurring. What is happening? This code works just not when I run it in eclipse ahhg

my LogCat:

```
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.fuchs.frontcam/com.fuchs.frontcam.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:258)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:220)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.fuchs.frontcam.MainActivity.initCamera(MainActivity.java:56)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.fuchs.frontcam.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:49)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  ... 12 more
```

Comment: Your package name includes `frontcam` which suggests you need a front camera...dumb question - you say the emulator has the camera option turned on but does that include a 'front' camera?

Comment: yes it does and so does the phone I am using when trying to launch it from eclipse directly to the phone. its a Galaxy S3

Comment: I uninstalled eclipse and re-installed it and same error is still occurring

Comment: Sorry, I've no further suggestions. I'm curious though - if you have a device you're able to test it on, why mess about with an emulator? I know you say it also doesn't work on the device when pushed out from eclipse but you could always just install on your device and use DDMS to monitor logcat. I use Bluetooth with a Push FTP Service and Astro to push out test copies of my apks to my devices - it takes 10-15 seconds to push them out, select in Astro, install and start them. OK, it doesn't answer your question but basically I rarely use eclipse for debugging and never use emulators.

Comment: okay thanks how do I use the ddms to monitor it on my device though?

Comment: I open up the ddms perspective in eclipse, but nothing shows up in the logcat below even though I have my device selected and when I run other apps that I know have errors and they crash nothing shows up in the logcat

Comment: Have you enable the USB debugging option on your device?

Comment: Weird I still get nothing in eclipse when I do that but I do see the log in android studio

Comment: Have you installed the eclipse USB drivers for your device? There are generic drivers but some makes/models require USB drivers from the manufacturer. Perhaps Android Studio does something different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I have had a similar issue.

The behavior appears to be random in the sense that my app worked sometimes but not others.  I believe it has something to do with timing in releasing objects and re-using them.

In my case I need to be able to re-use the camera over and over (continuously).

What I realized was the the `surfaceDestroyed` method was not guaranteed to be called (this is where I clean-up/release my camera object.

The solution I found was to clean-up/release the camera as soon as I was finished taking the photo.

In the following example you will not require all the lines of code,

My original surfaceDestoryed included this:

```
try {
    // Non camera related code
    .....        

    // Start of camera related code 
    // Only clean up what you need to
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        .....       
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
    previewing = false;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        LogUtils.error(LOG_TAG, "Problem in surfaceDestroyed"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Make sure that at least these two calls are made
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
}
```

I simply copied this code to the location after I was done taking my picture AND no longer needed the camera resources.

In the case of older devices 2.2.X - 4.0.X `surfaceDestroyed` was always called.  For many 4.1+ devices this does not seem to be the case.